# Get memory, cpu and disk usage for each tenant in Openstack

Tags: openstack

I am looking for the CPU, Memory and Disk consumption for each Tenant in Openstack,and their relationship by users, instances, flavors in use. Horizon only shows utilization of memory, cpu of a global way. Is it possible to get it with Openstack commands?

My openstack is based on Rocky.

Any ideas will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I know is

`openstack limits show --absolute --project <Project_ID/Tenant_ID>`

see also https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/limits.html

In the output you have information like for example `totalCoresUsed`, which represents the number of cores, which are used by the selected project.

Example:

```
root@openstack-controller:~# openstack limits show --absolute --project 416f937f505f4ff6b623c48a61228a86
+--------------------------+-------+
| Name                     | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| maxTotalInstances        |    10 |
| maxTotalCores            |    20 |
| maxTotalRAMSize          | 51200 |
| maxSecurityGroups        |    10 |
| maxTotalFloatingIps      |    10 |
| maxServerMeta            |   128 |
| maxImageMeta             |   128 |
| maxPersonality           |     5 |
| maxPersonalitySize       | 10240 |
| maxSecurityGroupRules    |    20 |
| maxTotalKeypairs         |   100 |
| maxServerGroups          |    10 |
| maxServerGroupMembers    |    10 |
| totalRAMUsed             |  2560 |
| totalCoresUsed           |     7 |
| totalInstancesUsed       |     7 |
| totalFloatingIpsUsed     |     0 |
| totalSecurityGroupsUsed  |     1 |
| totalServerGroupsUsed    |     0 |
| maxTotalVolumes          |    10 |
| maxTotalSnapshots        |    10 |
| maxTotalVolumeGigabytes  |  1000 |
| maxTotalBackups          |    10 |
| maxTotalBackupGigabytes  |  1000 |
| totalVolumesUsed         |     5 |
| totalGigabytesUsed       |     7 |
| totalSnapshotsUsed       |     0 |
| totalBackupsUsed         |     0 |
| totalBackupGigabytesUsed |     0 |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

The quotas and so the limitations are bind to projects and not to users, so I don't know if it is possible to get a relationshit by users. The only idea I would have, would a simple bash-script, which iterates over all instances and volumes of a project and collect the information of each ressource by the user, who created it.

### Update 30.7.2020:

Found a better solution now, which also allows to get the resource usage per user of a project. It comes with the new placement-component with the stein-release of openstack (tested in train-release of openstack).

Installation of the openstack-client extension: `pip install osc-placement`

**Ressource-usage of a project**:

`openstack resource usage show --os-placement-api-version 1.9 <PROJECT_ID>`

**Ressource-usage of a specific user within a project**:

`openstack resource usage show --os-placement-api-version 1.9 --user-id <USER_ID>  <PROJECT_ID>`

Example:

```
openstack resource usage show --os-placement-api-version 1.9 --user-id 98378bd3cdd94218bf7b6ef4ec80e74a  7733616a513444c2a106243db318b0dd
+----------------+-------+
| resource_class | usage |
+----------------+-------+
| VCPU           |     3 |
| MEMORY_MB      |   768 |
| DISK_GB        |     9 |
+----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tobias, It is very useful for me!.

Comment: @JavierRichardQuintoAncieta hi, updated my answer of your question here. Maybe its helpfull for you.